# Maximising the viewport in QGraphicsView when MainWindow is maximised

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create an application to view photos. For this, I have subclassed QWidget (named it ImageWidget). I am loading this widget inside a subclass of QMainWindow.

To Display the image, I am using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene. When I maximise the window, the size of the image loaded into QGraphicsView does not change. I want to image to increase and decresase according to the viewport.

I tried using the QWidget::resizeEevent provided, and using

```
this->imageView->fitInView(imageScene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

where 'this' refers to the ImageWidget object (subclass of QWidget).

The code I am trying is at Github: https://github.com/saurabhsood91/qt-photoviewer/blob/master/imagewidget.cpp

What might I be missing here?

Comment: With `onresize` event, do you mean [`QWidget::resizeEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent)?

Comment: yes. sorry for the error. I will update the question

Comment: Reimplementing `QWidget::resizeEvent` and using your code worked fine for me. I noticed you don't remove the old `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s when you add a new one, you should probably do that ([`QGraphicsScene::clear`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#clear))

Comment: It's not working for me: I tried the following code on  `code`this->imageScene->clear();
        `code`this->imageScene->addPixmap(QPixmap(this->items.at(this->currentIndex)));
        `code`this->imageView->fitInView(this->imageScene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        imageView->setScene(this->imageScene);

Comment: Ok. I got it working. Something was wrong with the code flow. Thanks. Could you set this as the answer? I can only upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimplementing `QWidget::resizeEvent` and using your code worked fine for me. I noticed you don't remove the old `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s when you add a new one, you should probably do that ([QGraphicsScene::clear](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#clear)) .

By the way you only need to set the scene to the view once. You do it in the constructor already so you don't need it in the `ImageWidget::setImage` method.